# How to use multiple GPU on each replica in Distributed Tensorflow Inception V3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

The [Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py) Here shows how to set each replica which has a single tower that uses one GPU.

The way I currently used for using all GPU on a worker machine is starting the number of workers that equal to the number of GPUs. then the workers can communicate to each other as if they are not on one machine. That is slower than if I can start a woker that control more than one GPU.

I'm wondering if there is a way changing this code a little bit to make use of multiple GPU on one machine like that example.

Answer (score 0):

Using a higher-level library will help. Slim has [utilities](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py) to deploy a model on multiple local GPUs.

Comment: Is there any code examples for distributed environment? Thanks

Comment: From the same repository, see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py

Comment: This code shows how to set each replica which has a single tower that uses only one GPU. But i want to make use of multiple GPU on each worker.

Comment: The first link I provided ( https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py#L321 ) has documentation on multi-gpu deploy.